# Everytime I run my code ffmpeg responds with this instead of doing its function. How do I fix?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version 2023-07-19-git-efa6cec759-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
  libavcodec     60. 22.100 / 60. 22.100
  libavformat    60. 10.100 / 60. 10.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9.  8.102 /  9.  8.102
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
```

Everytime I run the code it does this.

code:

```
import praw
import requests
import cv2
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

def download_video(url, filename):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)

def combine_videos(video_urls, output_filename):
    video_clips = []
    audio_clips = []
    for i, url in enumerate(video_urls):
        temp_filename = f'temp_video_{i}.mp4'
        download_video(url, temp_filename)
        video_clip = cv2.VideoCapture(temp_filename)
        audio_clip = AudioSegment.from_file(temp_filename, format="mp4")
        video_clips.append(video_clip)
        audio_clips.append(audio_clip)
    
    if not video_clips:
        print("No video clips to combine.")
        return

    frame_width = int(video_clips[0].get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(video_clips[0].get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fps = int(video_clips[0].get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    output_clip = cv2.VideoWriter(output_filename, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

    for i, video_clip in enumerate(video_clips):
        while True:
            ret, frame = video_clip.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            output_clip.write(frame)
    
    for video_clip in video_clips:
        video_clip.release()
    
    output_clip.release()

    # Combining audio using pydub
    combined_audio = sum(audio_clips)
    combined_audio.export("combined_audio.mp3", format="mp3")

    # Merging audio with video using ffmpeg
    os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {output_filename} -i combined_audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 final_output.mp4')

    # Cleaning up temporary files
    os.remove("combined_audio.mp3")

def main():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
       client_id='XXX',
        client_secret='XXX',
        user_agent='Reddit Video Downloader'
    )
    
    subreddit_name = input("Enter the name of the subreddit: ")
    limit = int(input("Enter the number of videos to download: "))
    
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name)
    submissions = subreddit.hot(limit=limit)
    
    video_urls = [submission.url for submission in submissions if submission.media and 'reddit_video' in submission.media]
    
    if video_urls:
        output_filename = input("Enter the output filename (e.g., output.mp4): ")
        combine_videos(video_urls, output_filename)
        print("Videos combined successfully!")
    else:
        print("No Reddit videos found in the subreddit.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyone got any idea why this happens?

I'm making a script that scrapes videos from a specific subreddit.

Also if it helps the temp video file is corrupted when it gets made.

I've put this into chatGPT as well and brought an expert friend and he hasn't been able to help me.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: The question needs to include enough information to let others see the problem themselves and test their answers **without** needing to follow links. See [mre] guidelines in the Help Center. (To understand why screenshots aren't permitted, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122); to understand why code links aren't acceptable _when critical to being able to reproduce the problem_, see [Is it okay to post Pastebin links if a critical portion of the question is too long?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187869))